# How did ancient Hindu scholars interpret the continent theory of Hindu scripture?

Tags: geography

The Hindu scriptures state that there are 7 dvipas or islands, and each is surrounded by a particular liquid.

For example, Jambudvipa is surrounded by an ocean of salt water.

From the [*Srimad Bhagavatam*](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/5/20/):

> Jambūdvīpa is also surrounded by an ocean of salt water.
>
> Plakṣadvīpa is surrounded by an ocean of sugarcane juice.
>
> Sālmalīdvīpa is surrounded by an equally broad body of water called
>   Surāsāgara, the ocean that tastes like liquor.
>
> Kuśadvīpa is surrounded by an ocean of liquid ghee.
>
> Krauñcadvīpa is surrounded by an ocean of milk.
>
> Śākadvīpa is surrounded by an ocean of churned yogurt.
>
> Puṣkaradvīpa is surrounded by an ocean of very tasteful water.

Where are these islands and oceans? What did ancient Hindu scholars say about the location of these islands and locations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are the 18 islands on Earth as mentioned in Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9677/where-are-the-18-islands-on-earth-as-mentioned-in-mahabharata)